# Competing JQuery Versions - Unknown Loadorder and JQuery.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question for you about jQuery.noConflict.

First of all - I did some research on what

```
jQuery.noConflict(true)
```

is, my question is related to this closely. So far I have found no answer that I was able to apply to my case, so if the answer is obvious and slipped my mind I apologize in advance.

The problem:

I am currently trying to solve a problem for a very large JS application. The JS application runs on a SAMSUNG browser (based on Orsay), which in turn runs on specific SAMSUNG displays.

To use display functions it is required to include:

```
<!-- TODO : Common API -->  
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Plugin.js'></script>
```

Also to use Deferred objects within the code jQuery 1.9.1 is included:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='app/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js' ></script>
```

My problem arises from the fact, that the SAMSUNG APIs apparently load whatever it is they are loading in the display's backend, however one of the things they load is their own jQuery version, which is 1.4.2.

The situation is such that I cannot say which version will be loaded at what point. I can start up the display five times having done no changes to the code and will get two times 1.4.2 and three times 1.9.1 or once 1.4.2 and four times 1.9.1 or any other possible order. I suspect this being due to the display's API able to run multithreading, so that the JS application and the API run independently from one another.

So I took a look at the noConflict method, however am unsure how to go about this problem using it.

As said, the application is large. It uses jQuery in various places. So doing something like

```
jQuery1_9_1 = $.noConflict(true);
```

after loading our jQuery version is rather unfeasible, since this will cost a large amount of time to fix.

However so far I have found no way to reliably unbind version 1.4.2 from $, because I do not load it, but the display's API does and it is not clear as to when it is loaded.

I hope this question is not redundant and someone has an idea how to go about it.

Comment: Aliasing jQuery is about your only choice if you want to absolutely ensure that the code relying on 1.4.2 is unaffected

Comment: The problem was discovered recently. All the code that was written was under the assumption of jQuery 1.9.1 running in the background, so there shouldn't be anything incompatible inside the applications. As described, it is only now that Deferred objects are to be introduced that this conflict is recognized. I am not sure if the SAMSUNG APIs rely on 1.4.2 for their code, however. If the latter is the case I think you're right. If not what I needed was a way to force my version through.

Comment: Oh by the way, thanks for the quick input!